# Xamarin MvvmCross how to use NLog for IMvxLogProvider?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, mvvmcross, nlog

I followed [Diagnostic & Logging](https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/fundamentals/logging) and install *NLog.Config* nuget package to Android & iOS project.

on Android project, *Setup.cs*

```
public override MvxLogProviderType GetDefaultLogProviderType() => MvxLogProviderType.NLog;
```

On Xamarin.Forms project,

```
private static readonly IMvxLog _logger = Mvx.IoCProvider.Resolve<IMvxLogProvider>().GetLogFor<CanvasContainer>();

_logger.Debug($"startScale: {startScale}, currentScale: {currentScale}");
```

> I checked `_logger` is not null.

Also, I changed *NLog.config*'s Build Action to *Embedded Resource*.

Here is Android Project's *NLog.config*,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd NLog.xsd"
      autoReload="true"
      throwExceptions="false"
      internalLogFile="c:\temp\nlog-internal.log">

  <targets>
    
    <target xsi:type="File" 
            name="FileTarget" 
            fileName="${specialfolder:folder=MyDocuments}/logs/${shortdate}.log" 
            layout="${longdate}|${level:uppercase=true}|${logger}|${message}" />
    
    <target xsi:type="ColoredConsole"
            name="ConsoleTarget"
            encoding="utf-8"
            layout="${longdate}|${level:uppercase=true}|${logger}|${message}"
            useDefaultRowHighlightingRules="true" />
    
  </targets>

  <rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="FileTarget" />
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="ConsoleTarget" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

Is there anything wrong with this set up? I can not find sample or tutorial for this...

Comment: Maybe enable exceptions and see if there is an exception: `throwExceptions="true"` (in `<nlog`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think you need to help NLog when having `NLog.config` as Embedded Resource:

```cs
    public override MvxLogProviderType GetDefaultLogProviderType() => MvxLogProviderType.NLog;
    
    protected override IMvxLogProvider CreateLogProvider()
    {
      var nlogConfigFile = GetEmbeddedResourceStream(myAssembly, "NLog.config");
      if (nlogConfigFile != null)
      {
        var xmlReader = System.Xml.XmlReader.Create(nlogConfigFile);
        NLog.LogManager.Configuration = new XmlLoggingConfiguration(xmlReader, null);
      }
      return base.CreateLogProvider();
    }

    private static Stream GetEmbeddedResourceStream(Assembly assembly, string resourceFileName)
    {
      var resourcePaths = assembly.GetManifestResourceNames()
        .Where(x => x.EndsWith(resourceFileName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        .ToList();
      if (resourcePaths.Count == 1)
      {
        return assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourcePaths.Single());
      }
      return null;
    }
```

See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Explicit-NLog-configuration-loading#loading-nlog-configuration-from-xamarin-resource